# What's the difference between PEX and DHT in the BitTorrent protocol?

Tags: networking, p2p, bittorrent, file-sharing, dht

If I understand correctly, the purpose of both PEX and DHT is to find other peers in the swarm. So why are both needed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [PEX BEP](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0011.html), I think the opening paragraph explains the differences well enough.